# (Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType) Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Actually sometimes I'm facing below issue.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Currently I'm using:
Rails : 6.0,
Ruby: 2.6.8

A Mime::Type::InvalidMimeType occurred in order_notifications#index:

"{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.httpservletresponse'].addheader('37kvs3il'" is not a valid MIME type

---

### Request:

ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary:

ActionView::Template::Error: "%{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.httpservletresponse'].addheader('37kvs3il'" is not a valid MIME type

/var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:235:in `initialize' /var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:143:in` new'
/var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:143:in `lookup' /var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb:23:in` block in content_mime_type'
/var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/request.rb:59:in `fetch' /var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/request.rb:59:in` fetch_header'
/var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_negotiation.rb:21:in `content_mime_type' /var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:255:in` media_type'
/var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:340:in `form_data?' /var/www/gaibu_ec/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/request.rb:334:in` POST'

Comment: My guess is that you have a bad client that is sending a garbage Content-Type or Accept-Type header. The correct thing for your Rails app to do in that case is to actually error out and return a 400 Bad Request or another status code that tells the client to get its sh*t sorted.